# appendChild error as I try to import in react

Tags: reactjs, npm, appendchild

I have been trying to use html code in react code but couldn't understand what to make changes. I know I am creating the container div via react but the constant container seems to be set before that but I don't understand where to make changes. Can someone modify the code so that I can run the below code in my react file ?

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const circlesArr = [];

for(let i=0; i<15; i++) {
    circlesArr[i] = [];
    for(let j=0; j<15; j++) {
        const circle = document.createElement('div');
        circle.classList.add('circle');
        container.appendChild(circle);
        circlesArr[i].push(circle); 
    }
}
function growCircles(i, j) {
    if(circlesArr[i] && circlesArr[i][j]) {
        if(!circlesArr[i][j].classList.contains('grow')) {
            circlesArr[i][j].classList.add('grow');
            setTimeout(() => {
                growCircles(i-1, j)
                growCircles(i+1, j)             
            }, 100)         
            setTimeout(() => {
                circlesArr[i][j].classList.remove('grow');
            }, 300);
        }
    }
}
circlesArr.forEach((15, i) => {
    cols.forEach((circle, j) => {
        circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
            growCircles(i, j);
        });
    });
});
  return (<div id="container" className="container"></div>)}
```